# Css selector does not work as I expected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've done some search/Google but it didn't lead anywhere. This is my problem, I have the following html structure (just a sample, list's length is dynamic):

```
<ul class="collection">
    <a class="collection-item head">Alvin</li>
    <a href="#" class="collection-item">Alvin</a>
    <a href="#" class="collection-item">Alvin</a>
    <a href="#" class="collection-item">Alvin</a>
    <a class="collection-item head">Alvin</li>
    <a href="#" class="collection-item">Alvin</a>
    <a href="#" class="collection-item">Alvin</a>
    <a href="#" class="collection-item">Alvin</a>
    <a class="collection-item head">Alvin</li>
    <a href="#" class="collection-item">Alvin</a>
    <a href="#" class="collection-item">Alvin</a>
    <a href="#" class="collection-item">Alvin</a>
</ul>
```

I want css them like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCYd3.png

I use css selector for all .head class to change border color of them:

```
.collection .head:nth-child(1){
    border-left: 5px solid green;
}
.collection .head:nth-child(2){
    border-left: 5px solid orange;
}
.collection .head:nth-child(3){
    border-left: 5px solid blue;
}
```

It worked on the first child of .collection but the 2nd and 3th one didn't change. I found that css selector count all of .collection's child not just .head class.

So I'm stuck right there. Does anyone know about this situation?

I have a good answer from **Saqib Amin** but I can't make it work. So I make a version of full jquery. Hope it useful for uguys.

```
$('.head').each(function(index) {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            $(this).css({
                property1: 'value1',
                property2: 'value2'
            });
            break;
        case 1:
            $(this).css({
                property1: 'value1',
                property2: 'value2'
            });
            break;
        case 2:
            $(this).css({
                property1: 'value1',
                property2: 'value2'
            });
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use id for those 3 fields, you actually know there are only 3 fields.

Comment: This html above is just a sample. List length following categories of website.

Comment: Why don't u use jquery for this?  Its easy like $('.collection').find('.head').each(function (){make the content appear from an array or any source});

Comment: @Kat: Your list length can be anything but does it have a specific pattern? That is, do you have 3 and only 3 collection items after every head element? By the way, what exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to assign a different color for each `.head` element? If yes, how would you do it without knowing how many such elements exist in the HTML?

Comment: thank you I guess I must use jquery for this situation.
But try to find some css way is always better, isn't it? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are providing wrong values for nth-child selector, your CSS should be like this:

```
.collection .head:nth-child(1){
    border-left: 5px solid green;
}
.collection .head:nth-child(5){
    border-left: 5px solid orange;
}
.collection .head:nth-child(9){
    border-left: 5px solid blue;
}
```

To Learn more about how nth-child selector works visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

As you said that number of items can vary so you should use a different solution, I suggest using jQuery to add indexing numbers to each of `.head` element and then style your elements using that indexing.

Your jQuery code will be:

```
var counter = 1;
$('.head').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-index', counter++);
});
```

and then your CSS will be like:

```
.collection .head[data-index=1] {
    border-left: 5px solid green;
}
.collection .head[data-index=2] {
    border-left: 5px solid orange;
}
.collection .head:[data-index=3] {
    border-left: 5px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: This list can have more childs. That html is just a sample then I can't use this way.

Comment: Are you dynamically generating list items? If yes, please mention name

Comment: Yes. My list's length following categories of the website. I've edited in my post. That was my mistake.. I should mention that.

Comment: Please see the updated answer above to add dynamic indexing to your elements

Comment: oh I didn't know this way can be possible. Thank you.. Sorry I can't vote you up...do not have enough reputation.

Comment: hmm I just test your code but your css doesn't work. Seem like I can't use data-index attribute.. So I made a version full of jquery... See the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

System takes `.collection` as parent then starts count for child so css should be

```
.collection .head:nth-child(1){
    border-left: 5px solid green;
}
.collection .head:nth-child(5){
    border-left: 5px solid orange;
}
.collection .head:nth-child(9){
    border-left: 5px solid blue;
}
```